# MVC Data Annotation Regex not allow White Space and Commas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have a property username in my model class on which I want to put a validation to restrict user to enter any white space or comma. Currently it's only restrict white space using the following regex but I want to restrict the comma as well. Please suggest

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "UserName")]        
[RegularExpression(@"^\S*$", ErrorMessage = "Username Cannot Have Spaces")]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try following  Regex, it matches white spaces and comma.

```
^[^\s\,]+$
```

Comment: Looks like it's doing revert. Unless I put either comma or white space it throws validation error. As soon as I edit any white or comma the validation passes.

Comment: surprisingly not seems to be working if I use regular form submission technique now. Previously I was using ajax and it works well in the case. Any idea?

Comment: @Ammar Khan guess, it is related to implementing `form` . can you provide any additional information ?

Comment: Actually I have a custom attribute as well on the same field and looks like that executing first before regular expression get a chance to validate the input.

Comment: @AmmarKhan probably, the reason why validation does not works, is MVC specific detail. You may fully describe your context and ask new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100251/discussion-between-ammar-khan-and-tchelidze).

Answer (score 2):

This one allows anything but comma and whitespace.

```
^[^\s\,]*$
```

Comment: The accepted answer mostly likely matches to your solution. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Probably '+' instead of '*'

Comment: @tchelidze The RegularExpression attribute is not supposed to check for emptiness. The Required attribute is here for that purpose.

Comment: @SandRock Nice, I did not know that.